# Pandas - use groupby to assign the minimum ID to all records in group

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Pandas Data Frame:

```
ID Name   Mascot
0  Team 1 Cat
1  Team 2 Rabbit
2  Team 1 Cat
3  Team 3 Rat
```

I want to assign the minimum ID in within each group to all records to be able to relate the duplicate records back to the IDs that are kept after de-duplication. Hence, my expected output is:

```
ID Name   Mascot Parent_ID
0  Team 1 Cat    0
1  Team 2 Rabbit 1
2  Team 1 Cat    0
3  Team 3 Rat    3
```

I have tried the below but this is assigning new IDs for each group.

```
df['Parent_ID'] = pd.factorize(list(zip(df['Name'], df['Mascot'])))[0] + 1
```

The output is:

```
ID Name   Mascot Parent_ID
0  Team 1 Cat    1
1  Team 2 Rabbit 2
2  Team 1 Cat    1
3  Team 3 Rat    3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, use `transform` broadcasting

```
df['Parent_ID'] = df.groupby('Name').ID.transform('min')

    ID  Name    Mascot  Parent_ID
0   0   Team 1  Cat     0
1   1   Team 2  Rabbit  1
2   2   Team 1  Cat     0
3   3   Team 3  Rat     3
```